# use custom QListWidgetItems in QListWidget

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

Hey I want to use custom QListWidgetItems in my QListWidget but I cannot get it to display at all.

I want the QListWidgetItem to look like this:

[image: custom QListWidgetItem]

Here is my code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PySide2.QtCore import QSize
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence, QFont, QPixmap, QWindow
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QShortcut, QLabel
from maya import OpenMayaUI
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sys

try:
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
    import shiboken
except:
    from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
    import shiboken2 as shiboken

allInfo = [{'label' : 'Giraffe',
            'command': 'print "The giraffe runs through the desert"',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the giraffe is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Dragon',
            'command': 'print "The dragon flies towards the divine sky."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the dragon is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Dog',
            'command': 'print "The dog barks at the neighbor."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the dog is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Cat',
            'command': 'print "The cat does give a damn."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the cat is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Bull',
            'command': 'print "The bull runs towards the bullfighter"',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the bull is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Ferret',
            'command': 'print "The ferret plays with the master."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the ferret is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Monkey',
            'command': 'print "The monkey is looking for bananas."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the monkey is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Bear',
            'command': 'print "The bear is looking for salmons."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the bear is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Ferret',
            'command': 'print "The ferret plays with the master."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the ferret is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Tiger',
            'command': 'print "The tiger tries to look like a cute cat.."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the tiger is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Lama',
            'command': 'print "The lama is spitting in your face."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the lama is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Lion',
            'command': 'print "The lion is looking for its prey."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the lion is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Fish',
            'command': 'print "The fish say blub."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the fish is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''},

            {'label' : 'Panda',
            'command': 'print "The panda eats some bamboo."',
            'annotation' : 'This command tells you what the bamboo is doing.',
            'image': '',
            'menu': ''}]


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        window = OpenMayaUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
        mayaWindow = shiboken.wrapInstance(long(window), QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(mayaWindow)

        self.setWindowTitle('Test Window')
        self.resize(630, 400)
        self._window = None

        # main widget
        mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        # layout initialize
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.HBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.VBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.VBoxLayout)
        self.VBoxLayout.addLayout(self.HBoxLayout)
        mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        # Add Widgets
        self.textField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.textField.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)

        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.listView.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.runCommand)

        self.HBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textField)
        self.VBoxLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.textField.setFocus()

    def onTextChanged(self):
        self.searchForCommands()

    def runCommand(self):
        index = self.listView.currentRow()
        input = self.textField.text()
        if input == '' or input.isspace() or input == ' ' or input == None:
            item = None
        else:
            try:
                item = self.listView.item(index).text()
            except(AttributeError):
                item = None
        if item != None:
            if allInfo != None:
                ExecuteCommand(item, input)

    def showWindow(self):
        self.closeWindow()
        if self._window is None:
            self._window = MainWindow()
            self._window.show()

    def closeWindow(self):
        self.close()

    def searchForCommands(self):        
        maxListLength = 20
        input = self.textField.text().lower()
        if input == '' or input.isspace() or input == ' ' or input == None:
            if self.listView.count() > 0:
                self.listView.clear()
        else:
            if self.listView.count() > 0:
                self.listView.clear()
            i = 0
            for x in range(len(allInfo)):
                if i < maxListLength:
                    label = allInfo[x].get('label')
                    if input in label.lower():
                        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(label)
                        #item = ListWidgetItem()
                        #item.SetIcon('')
                        #item.SetMenu('test menu')
                        #item.SetName(label)
                        #item.SetAnnotation('Test annotation.')
                        self.listView.addItem(item)
                        i += 1
                        continue
                    else:
                        pass
            self.listView.setCurrentRow(0)


class ListWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListWidgetItem, self).__init__()
        self.mainHBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.mainHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)

        self.rightVBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.menuNameHBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.rightVBoxLayout.addLayout(self.menuNameHBoxLayout)

        self.nameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.annotationLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.menuLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.menuNameHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.menuLabel)
        self.menuNameHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.nameLabel)
        self.rightVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.annotationLabel)

    def SetName(self, text):
        self.nameLabel.setText(text)

    def SetAnnotation(self, text):
        self.annotationLabel.setText(text)

    def SetIcon(self, iconPath = ''):
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(iconPath))

    def SetMenu(self, text):
        self.menuLabel.setText(text)


def startApp(*args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.showWindow()

def ExecuteCommand(listViewSelection, input, *args):
    ranCommand = False
    for x in range(len(allInfo)):
        if not ranCommand:
            if listViewSelection != None:
                label = allInfo[x].get('label')
                command = allInfo[x].get('command')
                if label == listViewSelection:
                    RunCommand(command)
                    ranCommand = True
        else:
            break

def RunCommand(command):
    cmds.evalDeferred(command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not cmds.about(batch = True):
        startApp()
```

The part that is commented out, on line 190 under searchForCommand, is my attempt to add the custom QListWidgetItem class that I have written in the script, but it does not work.

So how do I make it work so the QListWidgetItems looks like in the attached picture? The script works fine in Maya2020, just run it in the Script Editor, you have to double click on a QListWidgetItem to run its command. The ListWidgetItem class is my attempt to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using setItemWidget() along with regular QListWidgetItem.

For Example:

```
...

    def searchForCommands(self):        
        maxListLength = 20
        input = self.textField.text().lower()
        if input == '' or input.isspace() or input == ' ' or input == None:
            if self.listView.count() > 0:
                self.listView.clear()
        else:
            if self.listView.count() > 0:
                self.listView.clear()
            i = 0
            for x in range(len(allInfo)):
                if i < maxListLength:
                    label = allInfo[x].get('label')
                    if input in label.lower():
                        
                        itemWidget = ListWidgetItem()
                        itemWidget.SetIcon('')
                        itemWidget.SetMenu('test menu')
                        itemWidget.SetName(label)
                        itemWidget.SetAnnotation('Test annotation.')
  
                        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(label)
                        item.setSizeHint(itemWidget.sizeHint())
                        
                        self.listView.addItem(item)
                        self.listView.setItemWidget(item, itemWidget)
                        i += 1
                        continue
                    else:
                        pass
            self.listView.setCurrentRow(0)


class ListWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListWidgetItem, self).__init__()
                
        self.mainHBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainHBoxLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        
        self.iconLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(text="ICON")
        self.mainHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)
        
        self.rightVBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.rightVBoxLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.mainHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.rightVBoxLayout)

        self.menuNameHBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.menuNameHBoxLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)

        self.rightVBoxLayout.addLayout(self.menuNameHBoxLayout)
        self.nameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(text="Label")
        self.annotationLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Annotation")
        self.menuLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Menu")
        self.menuNameHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.menuLabel)
        self.menuNameHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.nameLabel)
        self.rightVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.annotationLabel)

        self.setLayout(self.mainHBoxLayout)

    def SetName(self, text):
        self.nameLabel.setText(text)

    def SetAnnotation(self, text):
        self.annotationLabel.setText(text)

    def SetIcon(self, iconPath = ''):
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(iconPath))

    def SetMenu(self, text):
        self.menuLabel.setText(text)


...
```

`item.setSizeHint(itemWidget.sizeHint())`
Is the most important line here. If you don't match the size it simply wont work.